# Add a custom stylesheet for BlackBerry

Tags: php, css

I want a little help loading a custom stylesheet in wordpress. I'm using PHP to check if the user agent is BlackBerry. If yes, I want to load blackberry.css, if no, regular wordpress style.css.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
   $pos_blackberry = strrpos($ua, "blackberry");
   $pos_webkit = strrpos($ua, "webkit");

   if (!($pos_blackberry === false)) {
      if (!($pos_webkit === false)) {

         **//load blackberry.css**

      }
   } else {
     wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwelve-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
   }
```

**Question:** what is the "grammatically correct" WordPress syntax for loading blackberry.css stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... You've already used [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style). Use it again. That is the canonical mechanism for loading stylesheets either by itself or in combination with [`wp_register_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style)

```
wp_enqueue_style('blackberry',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/path/to/blackberry.css');
```

I feel compelled to note that user agent sniffing is not especially reliable. Is it not possible to do this with media queries?

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, @s_ha_dum. How would you target a notoriously CSS-resistant BlackBerry with a media query? I'd appreciate your further advice!

Comment: Pure CSS question are off-topic per the [faq]. Try [so].

Comment: Well, @s_ha_dum, I wasn't asking a full-fledged question, but rather a further clarification of your reply to a question that was perfectly wordpress-related. Obviously, you know how to target BlackBerry devices with media queries, otherwise you wouldn't mention that method in your initial response in the first place. So why make it such a secret? Explaining it would only enrich your answer.

Comment: Actually, I asked _if_ there was a reason you can't do it with media queries. I wasn't claiming any particular expertise. Sorry for the confusion. Blackberry is such a tiny percent of the traffic I see (making up 0.13% of our traffic according to Google Analytics) I have never gone out of my way to tweak for it. I see more IE6 than that and I don't go out of my way for it either. But ... http://responsive.co.za/blackberry-specific-media-queries/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404617/blackberry-media-query should get you going.